# npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.5 npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am building a next JS application when I tried to run that I am getting an error saying node version not supported. so I tried to update my node version I tried lot commands specified in various resource. I tried to delete the path provided in the environment variables but there is no path named node JS in my environment variables. And also I tried to delete npm cache node-gyp and folders in my system but also I am getting errors. What is the issue here?
Here are the errors I get:

**C:\Users\LENOVO>npm install -g n**

npm notice
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -> 10.2.5
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.5
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.2.5 to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@9.2.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-16T13_52_45_735Z-debug-0.log

**C:\Users\LENOVO> npm install -g npm@10.2.5**

npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.5
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.5
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v18.12.1"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-16T13_53_18_837Z-debug-0.log

**C:\Users\LENOVO>npm install npm@latest -g**

npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.5
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.5
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v18.12.1"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-16T13_54_18_107Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node -v [check your current version]

nvm ls [displays all your installed version]

nvm install 18.17.0 [install a specific version]

nvm use 18.17.0 [switches to an installed version]

Comment: I don't have nvm. How to install it?

Comment: In the terminal add this to install nvm….       curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

Comment: Did that information work?